# Mailchimp API 3 to add subscriber not working - from Flask

Tags: python, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm trying to add subscriber using Flask. My code is:

```
import mailchimp
def subscribe():
    user_data = request.get_json();
    email = user_data['email']
    api_key = 'xxx'
    list_id = 'xxx' 
    api = mailchimp.Mailchimp(api_key)
    mailchimp_res = api.lists.subscribe(list_id, {'email': email, 'status': 'subscribed', 'double_optin': False})
    return jsonify({
        'result': True
    })
```

When I run this code mailchimp_res has only 3 fields:

```
{
'email': 'tess@testing.com', 
'euid': 'someid', 
'leid': 'anotherid'
}
```

and it actually didn't add this email to the list. Accordingly to the API docs https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#create-post_lists_list_id_members the response should have more fields, and at least add new subscribers!

What am I doing wrong?

UPD I found the solution, finally. I had to add one more parameter double_optin = False to api.lists.subscribe instead of putting it into struct "email".